# what's the difference between mt-gd and mt-s library

Tags: boost

In the boost, there are two types of libs, one is ending with `mt-gd`, the other is ending with `mt-s`. What's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Read [Boost Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)

- mt : multi threaded
- d : Add ABI tags, could be used with:

  - g : using debug versions of the standard and runtime support libraries.
  - s : linking statically to the standard and runtime support libraries.
  - and more

Comment: When building in windows using .\b2, it builds the mt and mt-g libraries by default.  To build mt-s libraries, use `.\b2 runtime-link=static`.  The libraries are created in the 'stage' directory rather than the 'libs' directory by default.

Answer (score 21):

As pointed out in the other answers and comments, these represent different configurations. With this answer, I'd like to give a more complete overview and link to the corresponding Visual Studio configurations:

1. Boost's `-mt-s` corresponds to VS' *Runtime Library* setting `/MT`
2. Boost's `-mt-sgd` corresponds to VS' *Runtime Library* setting `/MTd`
3. Boost's `-mt` corresponds to VS' *Runtime Library* setting `/MD`
4. Boost's `-mt-gd` corresponds to VS' *Runtime Library* setting `/MDd`

First and second can be built with `./b2 runtime-link=static threading=multi`
Third and fourth can be built with `./b2 runtime-link=shared threading=multi`

Comment: Great comprehensive answer. You saved the day!