# C++ Boost: Multiple .lib files, which one to use (s, sg?)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I recently rebuilt Boost 1.59 using the compiler that comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 (2015). Before, when I compiled with MingW (gcc), I got 2 versions; debug and release. However, looking at the file list now, it looks like this:

```
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ450 libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            60ÿ080 libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ488 libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:08            60ÿ118 libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           320ÿ248 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ054ÿ488 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           321ÿ418 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ845ÿ708 libboost_chrono-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           321ÿ322 libboost_chrono-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ845ÿ612 libboost_chrono-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10            55ÿ012 libboost_container-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           192ÿ838 libboost_container-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            55ÿ298 libboost_container-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           179ÿ142 libboost_container-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            55ÿ266 libboost_container-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           179ÿ110 libboost_container-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           308ÿ192 libboost_context-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ178ÿ266 libboost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           309ÿ750 libboost_context-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ082ÿ028 libboost_context-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           336ÿ128 libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ591ÿ224 libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           337ÿ982 libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ425ÿ546 libboost_coroutine-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           337ÿ886 libboost_coroutine-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ425ÿ450 libboost_coroutine-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           691ÿ856 libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ963ÿ132 libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           728ÿ488 libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ819ÿ108 libboost_date_time-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           728ÿ392 libboost_date_time-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ819ÿ012 libboost_date_time-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10             1ÿ506 libboost_exception-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            32ÿ214 libboost_exception-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10             1ÿ546 libboost_exception-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            32ÿ252 libboost_exception-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10             1ÿ514 libboost_exception-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            32ÿ220 libboost_exception-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           863ÿ302 libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         5ÿ998ÿ290 libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           898ÿ982 libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         5ÿ112ÿ310 libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           898ÿ726 libboost_filesystem-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         5ÿ112ÿ054 libboost_filesystem-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         6ÿ363ÿ494 libboost_graph-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        16ÿ243ÿ546 libboost_graph-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         6ÿ690ÿ912 libboost_graph-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        16ÿ443ÿ534 libboost_graph-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         6ÿ690ÿ848 libboost_graph-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        16ÿ443ÿ470 libboost_graph-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           473ÿ362 libboost_iostreams-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ815ÿ392 libboost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           474ÿ962 libboost_iostreams-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ574ÿ632 libboost_iostreams-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           474ÿ898 libboost_iostreams-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ574ÿ568 libboost_iostreams-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         7ÿ975ÿ322 libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ839ÿ386 libboost_locale-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         9ÿ119ÿ600 libboost_locale-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ089ÿ064 libboost_locale-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        14ÿ657ÿ346 libboost_log-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        62ÿ537ÿ226 libboost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        16ÿ632ÿ428 libboost_log-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        63ÿ052ÿ840 libboost_log-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        14ÿ320ÿ424 libboost_log-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        55ÿ108ÿ712 libboost_log-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ103ÿ502 libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        68ÿ874ÿ134 libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ895ÿ836 libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        69ÿ148ÿ192 libboost_log_setup-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        21ÿ127ÿ762 libboost_log_setup-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        64ÿ347ÿ312 libboost_log_setup-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           607ÿ640 libboost_math_c99-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ905ÿ858 libboost_math_c99-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           612ÿ486 libboost_math_c99-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ795ÿ704 libboost_math_c99-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           611ÿ398 libboost_math_c99-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ793ÿ528 libboost_math_c99-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           610ÿ896 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ885ÿ668 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           615ÿ886 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ775ÿ406 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           614ÿ798 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ773ÿ230 libboost_math_c99f-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           587ÿ958 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ858ÿ540 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           592ÿ840 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ749ÿ358 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           591ÿ752 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ747ÿ182 libboost_math_c99l-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ319ÿ740 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        25ÿ929ÿ052 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ303ÿ908 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ854ÿ126 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ302ÿ820 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ851ÿ726 libboost_math_tr1-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ619ÿ472 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        26ÿ474ÿ838 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ615ÿ718 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        29ÿ412ÿ826 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ614ÿ630 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        29ÿ410ÿ426 libboost_math_tr1f-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ257ÿ650 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        25ÿ784ÿ866 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ241ÿ884 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ711ÿ672 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ240ÿ796 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        28ÿ709ÿ272 libboost_math_tr1l-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           259ÿ864 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ929ÿ930 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           446ÿ682 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ030ÿ032 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           446ÿ586 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         2ÿ030ÿ032 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         7ÿ935ÿ008 libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        25ÿ054ÿ254 libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         8ÿ309ÿ586 libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        24ÿ339ÿ466 libboost_program_options-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         8ÿ309ÿ234 libboost_program_options-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        24ÿ339ÿ114 libboost_program_options-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         4ÿ859ÿ036 libboost_python-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        25ÿ116ÿ880 libboost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         4ÿ953ÿ686 libboost_python-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ404ÿ266 libboost_python-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         4ÿ952ÿ790 libboost_python-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ403ÿ370 libboost_python-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           134ÿ554 libboost_random-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           701ÿ682 libboost_random-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           134ÿ948 libboost_random-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           632ÿ226 libboost_random-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           134ÿ916 libboost_random-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           632ÿ194 libboost_random-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ804ÿ368 libboost_regex-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        41ÿ594ÿ200 libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ881ÿ652 libboost_regex-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        40ÿ039ÿ890 libboost_regex-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ881ÿ108 libboost_regex-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        40ÿ039ÿ346 libboost_regex-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         9ÿ398ÿ596 libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        31ÿ982ÿ026 libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ619ÿ172 libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        32ÿ656ÿ306 libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ618ÿ308 libboost_serialization-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        32ÿ655ÿ442 libboost_serialization-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ085ÿ094 libboost_signals-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         5ÿ198ÿ988 libboost_signals-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ087ÿ834 libboost_signals-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         4ÿ847ÿ364 libboost_signals-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ087ÿ674 libboost_signals-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         4ÿ847ÿ204 libboost_signals-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10            80ÿ728 libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           619ÿ740 libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            81ÿ136 libboost_system-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:08           550ÿ276 libboost_system-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            81ÿ104 libboost_system-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           550ÿ244 libboost_system-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ409ÿ526 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        35ÿ239ÿ478 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ163ÿ864 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        36ÿ680ÿ558 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ163ÿ288 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        36ÿ680ÿ558 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ132ÿ450 libboost_thread-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ892ÿ092 libboost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ135ÿ758 libboost_thread-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         3ÿ723ÿ028 libboost_thread-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10           145ÿ172 libboost_timer-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ244ÿ894 libboost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           362ÿ702 libboost_timer-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ391ÿ376 libboost_timer-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           362ÿ638 libboost_timer-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ391ÿ408 libboost_timer-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        10ÿ325ÿ104 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        34ÿ269ÿ392 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ026ÿ400 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        35ÿ676ÿ198 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        12ÿ025ÿ856 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        35ÿ676ÿ198 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10        37ÿ273ÿ334 libboost_wave-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        93ÿ579ÿ450 libboost_wave-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        37ÿ751ÿ046 libboost_wave-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        93ÿ491ÿ990 libboost_wave-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
------
2016-05-29  22:10         7ÿ253ÿ358 libboost_wserialization-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        22ÿ272ÿ954 libboost_wserialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         8ÿ653ÿ696 libboost_wserialization-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ928ÿ610 libboost_wserialization-vc140-mt-sgd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         8ÿ653ÿ408 libboost_wserialization-vc140-s-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10        23ÿ928ÿ322 libboost_wserialization-vc140-sgd-1_59.lib
```

There's also a bunch of files beginning with just `boost`:

```
2016-05-29  22:10             9ÿ216 boost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ442 boost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            13ÿ312 boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ490 boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            29ÿ184 boost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            24ÿ492 boost_chrono-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            46ÿ592 boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            24ÿ630 boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            28ÿ160 boost_container-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             7ÿ002 boost_container-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            71ÿ168 boost_container-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             7ÿ094 boost_container-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            53ÿ760 boost_context-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            19ÿ644 boost_context-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            98ÿ816 boost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            19ÿ804 boost_context-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            52ÿ736 boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            19ÿ676 boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            97ÿ280 boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            19ÿ830 boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            49ÿ664 boost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            29ÿ584 boost_date_time-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           107ÿ520 boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            29ÿ768 boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           113ÿ664 boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           100ÿ384 boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           164ÿ864 boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           100ÿ990 boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           219ÿ136 boost_graph-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ212 boost_graph-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           558ÿ080 boost_graph-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ258 boost_graph-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            48ÿ640 boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            45ÿ818 boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            76ÿ288 boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            46ÿ160 boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           398ÿ848 boost_locale-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            89ÿ198 boost_locale-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           760ÿ832 boost_locale-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            89ÿ810 boost_locale-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           553ÿ472 boost_log-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           254ÿ162 boost_log-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ172ÿ992 boost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           255ÿ350 boost_log-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           521ÿ728 boost_log_setup-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            24ÿ240 boost_log_setup-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ294ÿ336 boost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            24ÿ402 boost_log_setup-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            34ÿ304 boost_math_c99-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             7ÿ996 boost_math_c99-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            67ÿ584 boost_math_c99-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ112 boost_math_c99-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            34ÿ816 boost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ134 boost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            69ÿ120 boost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ250 boost_math_c99f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            32ÿ768 boost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ134 boost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            62ÿ976 boost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             8ÿ250 boost_math_c99l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           179ÿ200 boost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ750 boost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           439ÿ296 boost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ838 boost_math_tr1-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           189ÿ952 boost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ886 boost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           473ÿ600 boost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ978 boost_math_tr1f-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           179ÿ200 boost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ886 boost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           438ÿ272 boost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             6ÿ978 boost_math_tr1l-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            40ÿ448 boost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            16ÿ402 boost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            66ÿ048 boost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            16ÿ536 boost_prg_exec_monitor-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           381ÿ952 boost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           514ÿ820 boost_program_options-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           704ÿ512 boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           529ÿ526 boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            22ÿ528 boost_random-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ830 boost_random-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            35ÿ840 boost_random-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             3ÿ874 boost_random-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           638ÿ976 boost_regex-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ089ÿ018 boost_regex-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ899ÿ520 boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ092ÿ282 boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           207ÿ360 boost_serialization-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           202ÿ044 boost_serialization-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           552ÿ448 boost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           202ÿ864 boost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            52ÿ736 boost_signals-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            61ÿ742 boost_signals-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           132ÿ608 boost_signals-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            62ÿ518 boost_signals-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            20ÿ480 boost_system-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             2ÿ938 boost_system-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            33ÿ280 boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10             2ÿ980 boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            92ÿ672 boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            28ÿ724 boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           169ÿ984 boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            28ÿ972 boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            29ÿ184 boost_timer-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            14ÿ690 boost_timer-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10            46ÿ592 boost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            14ÿ800 boost_timer-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           404ÿ480 boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           239ÿ226 boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ103ÿ360 boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           240ÿ668 boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           652ÿ288 boost_wave-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           145ÿ190 boost_wave-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10         1ÿ291ÿ264 boost_wave-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10           145ÿ326 boost_wave-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           146ÿ432 boost_wserialization-vc140-mt-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            78ÿ792 boost_wserialization-vc140-mt-1_59.lib
2016-05-29  22:10           335ÿ872 boost_wserialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.dll
2016-05-29  22:10            79ÿ100 boost_wserialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
```

So my question is: What's the difference between the different files? Which one should I choose?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `libboost*.lib` ones are for static linking. `boost*.lib` and `boost*.dll` pairs are for dynamic linking. You can disable building one or another by passign flags to `b2` (see `b2 --help`). P.S. Default automatic linking (`#pragma comment(lib, ...)`) can be disabled by adding a preprocessor definition `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to the compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to also know the difference between the `s` and `sg` and `<nothing>` versions of `libboost`?

Comment: Yes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming), [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014517/whats-the-difference-between-mt-gd-and-mt-s-library) and [official docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html)