# Boost regex linker error with cl 19

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex, cl

I use boost 1.61.0 with cl 19 (visual studio 2015). I built boost libraries from getting start documentation with command line `bootstrap`and `.\b2`. This made stage directory with some vc14 prefix libraries.

But when I tried to compile getting start regex program

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

with this command line compiler settings:

```
cl main.cpp -I %BOOST_ROOT% -L %BOOST_LIB_14% /EHsc
```

I get this error:

```
Link:: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\local\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib.obj
```

What is wrong with my try?

**EDIT**: I changed command line compile to:

```
cl main.cpp /I %BOOST_ROOT% /link /LIBPATH:%BOOST_LIB_14% /EHsc
```

Now, I get this error:

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libbosst_regex-vc140-mt-s-1_61.lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I had built boost libraries with `bootstrap` and `.\b2` commands. It built `mt` (multithread) and `gd` (debug) libraries only.

For static link (`s`) libraries I tried `.\b2 runtime-link=static` and that buit 'libbosst_regex-vc140-mt-s-1_61.lib' file and now everything is OK.

I found the point at [what's the difference between mt-gd and mt-s library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014517/whats-the-difference-between-mt-gd-and-mt-s-library).